# django collectstatic 'AppConfig' object has no attribute 'ignore_patterns'

Tags: python, django, collectstatic

I recently upgraded django to 3.2.5, after which admin template was not loading correctly especially in model pages, please see the screenshot,

[image: Django Admin model page]

I decided to run,

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

but then I am receiving following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/var/www/dev.bluelion.icu/bluelion/manage.py", line 21, in 
> main()   File "/var/www/dev.bluelion.icu/bluelion/manage.py", line 17, in main
> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/var/www/dev.bluelion.icu/bluelion/bluelionenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
> line 419, in execute_from_command_line
> utility.execute()   File "/var/www/dev.bluelion.icu/bluelion/bluelionenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
> line 413, in execute
> self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/var/www/dev.bluelion.icu/bluelion/bluelionenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 354, in run_from_argv
> self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "/var/www/dev.bluelion.icu/bluelion/bluelionenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 398, in execute
> output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/var/www/dev.bluelion.icu/bluelion/bluelionenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py",
> line 149, in handle
> self.set_options(**options)   File "/var/www/dev.bluelion.icu/bluelion/bluelionenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py",
> line 82, in set_options
> ignore_patterns += apps.get_app_config('staticfiles').ignore_patterns AttributeError:
> 'AppConfig' object has no attribute 'ignore_patterns'

Any help is appreciated, please let me know if there is any ambiguity in the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, it was this line of code: `AppConfig.default = False`

I added it because it fixed a different error message. But when I ran collectstatic it showed me your error.

Comment: What is workaround for this. If I remove this line (AppConfig.default = False) it starts showing other error message.

Comment: @WaqasAli In my case, the error message was caused by the wrong identifier in my apps.py. I was setting a name of an app inside a folder. Like this: 
inside django-app-name/blog-app/apps.py
`class BlogAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'blog-app'
`
I fixed the error by changing the name to:
`name = 'django-app-name.blog-app'`